# How to avoid parent element's height jumping when displaying a child div with v-if

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, transition

I have a parent div and a child div. Child div is displayed via v-if. I can add a transition to the child element but once the transition is over the parent's height changes abruptly and it doesn't look nice.

I'd like something like the jQuery's slideToggle() function.

Here's my html where I'm using fade effect by transitioning the `opacity`:

```
  <div class="my-div">
    <p>some content</p>
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <p key=1 v-if="show">hello</p>
    </transition>
  </div>
```

and here's the transition css:

```
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0
}

.my-div {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

Here is the fiddle with my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/x15Lw6a3/

I don't know how to make the height transition. I've tried switching from `opacity` to `height` and to `max-height` as per some other questions but it just snaps up and down.

Any idea or a link to tutorial is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you want. Do you want the parent div to retain it's height after the child has disappeared or do you want the height of the parent div to decrease smoothly?

Comment: I need parent's height to increase as the child shows up, and then to decrease when the child disappear. The fade is here just for an example to show what I understand so far. In place of the fade effect I need the height-change effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `max-height` property  by adding `max-height: 100px;` to `fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active` rule and in `.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to` rule set it 0 as follows:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  max-height: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0px;
}

.my-div {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <div class="my-div">
  <p>some content</p>
  <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <p key=1 v-if="show" >hello</p>
  </transition>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note:

You could see that the animation is not perfectly smooth

Comment: The stuttering is not really noticable when you set the transition duration to `0.05s` which is OK for my scenario. Any idea or further-reading materials why is this not working properly?

Comment: i read this [article](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/transition-to-height-auto-with-vue/) which could help you

Answer (score 1):

Tried a number of approaches myself, ended up going for a component, and [`VueSlideToggle`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-slide-toggle) does the job perfectly for me. It makes use of CSS transition targeting the `height` property.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',

  data() {
    return {
      show: true
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.my-div {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">Toggle</button>

  <div class="my-div">
    <p>some content</p>

    <vue-slide-toggle :open="show" tag="div" :duration="500">
      <p v-if="show">hello</p>
    </vue-slide-toggle>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-slide-toggle"></script>
```